# phpspreadsheet setCellValue is not writing

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I am uploading a excel file, reading the contents and writing to a new excel file using phpspreadsheet.

I am trying to create a excel file.

I am writing into cells using the following code

```
$writesheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('A1','myemail@gmail.com');
```

these lines

```
        echo 'valid';
        echo $cell;
        echo $toemail;
```

print all the values correctly.

But this line of code is not working..

Full code:

```
<?php
include '../includes/common.php';
include "class.emailvalidator.php";






/////////////////////////////////////EXCEL READER ////////////////////////////////
if(!empty($_FILES)){
    require 'spreadsheet/vendor/autoload.php';
    $file = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'];
    $file_name = $_FILES['files']['name'];
    $upload_path = 'files/'.$file_name;


    if(move_uploaded_file($file,$upload_path)){
        $spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load($upload_path);
        $worksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
        $highestRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow();

        for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; ++$row) {
            $toemail = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, $row)->getValue();
            $fromemail = 'admin@myimsuite.com';

            $details = verifyEmail($fromemail,$toemail,true);

            $writesheet = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet();

            $cell = 'A'.$row;
            if($details[0]== 'valid'){
            echo 'valid';
            echo $cell;
            echo $toemail;
                $writesheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue($cell, $toemail);
            }elseif($details[0]== 'invalid'){

            }


        }
        if(file_exists($upload_path)){
            unlink($upload_path);
        }
        $writer = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx($writesheet);

        $fxls ='excel-file_1.xlsx';
        $writer->save($fxls);        
        if(file_exists($fxls)){
            //force_download($fxls);        
        }

    }


die();

}

   function force_download($filename) {
    $filedata = @file_get_contents($filename);

    // SUCCESS
    if ($filedata)
    {
        // GET A NAME FOR THE FILE
        $basename = basename($filename);

        // THESE HEADERS ARE USED ON ALL BROWSERS
        header("Content-Type: application-x/force-download");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$basename");
        header("Content-length: " . (string)(strlen($filedata)));
        header("Expires: ".gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", mktime(date("H")+2, date("i"), date("s"), date("m"), date("d"), date("Y")))." GMT");
        header("Last-Modified: ".gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s")." GMT");

        // THIS HEADER MUST BE OMITTED FOR IE 6+
        if (FALSE === strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"], 'MSIE '))
        {
            header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
        }

        // THIS IS THE LAST HEADER
        header("Pragma: no-cache");

        // FLUSH THE HEADERS TO THE BROWSER
        flush();

        // CAPTURE THE FILE IN THE OUTPUT BUFFERS - WILL BE FLUSHED AT SCRIPT END
        ob_start();
        echo $filedata;
    }

    // FAILURE
    else
    {
        die("ERROR: UNABLE TO OPEN $filename");
    }
}

/////////////////////////////////////EXCEL READER ////////////////////////////////



////////////////////////Email Related//////////////////////////////
//var_dump($log);

////////////////////////End Email Related//////////////////////////////
$objSmarty->assign("page",'bannerindex');

$objSmarty->setTemplateDir("../templates");
$objSmarty->display("email_validator.tpl");
?>
```

Comment: I have the same problem. What is interesting is that this function worked in PHPExcel and no longer in Phpspreadsheet. For me it doesn't work in ODS or XLSX but in XLS it does - so for any other readers it may be worth a try changing to XLS.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `$writer->setPreCalculateFormulas(false);` - fixed it for me